# Java + Mysql from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have one database with encoding of Windows Baltic(windows-1257). I copy the data to other database with encoding UTF-8 Lithuanian (using sql language). After copying data, I still don't get UTF-8 values - "Nerûdijantis plienas" and I need "Nerūdijantis plienas". And I made little Java application, witch should take data from UTF-8 db with data copied from Latin db and `System.out.println(..)`. But now since data is still wrong after copying i get wrong encoding printed out. What should I do? Should i copy data with some kind of encoding sentences or should i use Java to change encoding during printing out?

**EDIT**:I need something like iconv in PHP, it works when I use it to convert data.

Comment: maybe there http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions is better place for simlair questions

Comment: You see, it's not that I would like to change encoding of the data. If it's possible, I would like only in java to convert String from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 encoding on printing it out.

Comment: I still think that why convert in/output from/to JDBC , let's Sql Engine returns correct chars, btw you can flag your own question with ask for moving to dba.stackexchange.com/questions forum,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flagged this thread as needed to move to different forum, but since nothing was made, I got it working [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/mysql-transfer-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8/10056#10056).

Answer (score 1):

maybe help you to use [MySql Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-collation-charset.html),

Answer (score 0):

**To convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 we can use following code**

//convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

```
byte[] utf8 = new String(dataInString, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or have a look on java.nio.Charset

see
[Converting UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in Java - how to keep it as single byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655891/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java-how-to-keep-it-as-single-byte)

Answer (score 0):

Of course in the database the text should be in UTF-8. You can do a **mysqldump** just of one concerned table to check where it is going wrong.

A nice programmer's editor like **JEdit** (http://jedit.org) can switch encodings, which may help.

A web server would need to do response.setContentText("text/html; charset=UTF-8").
A normal application should have no problem, as Unicode is used internally by Java,
and the operating system encoding is that of Lithuanian: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

For the Java MySQL driver you will need to set the communication to UTF-8 too:
[Character encoding issue with linux and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384842/character-encoding-issue-with-linux-and-mysql)

System.out.println prints in the default system encoding, which might be misleading.
Best is a hex dump of the bytes, so you can actual check.

Comment: It's not web service. As for communication, it is set and doesn't work. JEdit if I understand, you suggest to dump my DB and switch dump.sql file encoding to UTF-8? If so, it doesn't help. If I switch, characters remain like they was.